# Send message to service worker to skip waiting

Tags: javascript, service-worker

How do you send a message to a service worker to skip waiting? Service worker is defined with the following handler

```
self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});
```

Thanks,
Luis

Comment: This is an interesting approach. I had not thought about possibly doing a battery of validation checks once a new service worker is installed to see if it is safe to activate or not.
You would need to catch the message from the new service worker in your UI code to initiate the diagnostics first. Once things pass then you can trigger the activation by sending a message back to the service worker.
However, I bet you wont get far because the client-side tests would depend on having new assets (HTML, JS, CSS, etc) loaded in the client, so most likely the test wont pass.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example on how I do it in one of my projects.

```
navigator.serviceWorker
  .register(swUrl)
  .then(registration => {
    this.registration = registration;
    config.onRegistration();

    registration.onupdatefound = () => {
      const installingWorker = registration.installing;
      if (installingWorker == null) {
        return;
      }
      config.onUpdateFound();
      installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
        if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
          if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
            registration.waiting.postMessage('skipWaiting');
            config.onUpdateInstalled();
          }
        } else if (installingWorker.state === 'activated') {
          config.onActivated();
        }
      };
    };
  })
```

Comment: Thank you. Question: Where did you get the config from? used here config.onRegistration() and here config.onUpdateInstalled();

Comment: I am using create-react-app, and although th message is sent per Joel's code, the service worker remains in waiting status